# get each post number of views count pdo

Tags: pdo

i am new in pdo. want to echo number of times post viewed. each time a user view it will add +1 autometically. i created a table views that type int length 16. my code is below

```
<?php
        try {


            $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate, views FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID ASC');
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                echo '<div>';
                    echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                    echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                    echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>'; 
                    echo $row['views']; echo "times";           
                    echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';
                    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_posts SET views = views+1 WHERE postID = :postID') ;                      
                echo '</div>';

               }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: its returning 0times

Comment: i want to show number times post viewed but it is returning 0 times always

Answer (score 0):

You just prepare update statement not execute so execute the prepare statement .

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_posts SET views = views+1 WHERE postID = :postID') ; 

 $stmt->execute(array(':postID'=>$row['postID']));
```